The given value is not suitable for module.bucket_init.var.kms_master_key_id declared string required
I have a root module with three levels of call:
module.this
   module.kms
      module.kms_init

In the root module call I reference the kms_key_id or kms_key_arn output of the module.kms_init.
I have in the second level the following outputs for this module:
output "key_arn" { 
description = "The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the key" 
value = try(module.kms[*].*) 
} 

output "key_id" { 
description = "The globally unique identifier for the key" 
value = try(module.kms[*].*) 
} 

the first level is a Terraform AWS modules with the following outputs:
output "key_arn" {

description = "The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) of the key"
value = try(aws_kms_key.this[0].arn,aws_kms_external_key.this[0].arn, aws_kms_replica_key.this[0].arn, aws_kms_replica_external_key.this[0].arn, null)

}

output "key_id" {

description = "The globally unique identifier for the key"
value = try(aws_kms_key.this[0].key_id, aws_kms_external_key.this[0].id, aws_kms_replica_key.this[0].key_id, aws_kms_replica_external_key.this[0].key_id, null)

}

the reference to this module and this output is the following:
kms_master_key_id = module.kms_init.key _id 
and it gives me this error:
The given value is not suitable for module.bucket_init.var.kms_master_key_id declared at .terraform\modules\bucket_init\variables.tf:588,1-29: string required, 

can you help me please?
I am trying to pass the kms key arn value to an s3 bucket for encryption.

Can you warp try function in a tostring function the error returned shows that the value must be a string.
